# Why AWS is retiring Elastic Beanstalk with multi container support?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was looking at using Elastic Beanstalk with Multicontainer support, although, it seems that AWS is scheduling the retirement of this platform / functionality.

Here is the documentation for supported platform for Elastic Beanstalk: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html

I used the Docker version `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Docker` and that version does not support using `Dockerrun.aws.json` version 2 with multi containers support.

So then I came across this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-retiring.html#platforms-retiring.mcdocker

Multi containers support is marked as retiring platform, I was wondering why basically?
Is there a version coming soon or Elastic Beanstalk would just stop doing multi containers support?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Multicontainer Docker (Amazon Linux AMI)` was based on ECS to support muliti-container docker. But since regular [Docker environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker.html) now supports **docker-compose** you can multi-containers without ECS:

> Docker Compose features. This platform will allow you to leverage the features provided by the Docker Compose tool to define and **run multiple containers**. You can include the docker-compose.yml file to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk.

Docker Compose makes is much easier to use multi-containers on EB, thus support for ECS seems redundant.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for this reply. You're right, the `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.4 running Docker` is supporting `Dockerrun.aws.json` version 3 and use docker-compose instead. I will dig a bit more on this!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this tool will be used for containerized web applications- https://aws.amazon.com/apprunner/

Comment: Thanks smac2020 for your reply. I didn't know this solution was existing too. I've got to check now that's the difference with ECS/Fargate and app runner solution. Sounds like they're doing the proxy / networking settings on your behalf too.